# Appending to an array attribute of an array of instances

Tags: python, arrays, class, scope, attributes

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [0]*10
```

And then I use it as:

```
arrOfTests = [test()]*10
arrOfTests[0].arr.insert(0,1)
print arrOfTests[0].arr[0]
print arrOfTests[1].arr[0]
```

Which returns

```
1
1
```

Why is arr[0] of attOfTests[1] (and also all the others) 1 as well? By all my best effort, I could not figure this out.. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you got a list of references to the same one object

Comment: `id(arrOfTest[0]) == id(arrOfTest[1])`

Comment: Thank you! Finally I could match your reply with my problem. Now it works on my code :)